# Ruby each_slice into sub arrays and set default element values if last sub-array is different size to other sub-arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array:

```rb
["1", "b", "0", "7", "9", "2", "a", "a", "5", "7"]
```

Which I want to convert to:

```rb
 [["1", "b", "0"], ["7", "9", "2"], ["a", "a", "5"], ["7", false, false]]
```

Tried using `each_slice` but returns the sub-array without the `false` values:

```rb
array = ["1", "b", "0", "7", "9", "2", "a", "a", "5", "7"]
array.each_slice(3).to_a
#=> [["1", "b", "0"], ["7", "9", "2"], ["a", "a", "5"], ["7"]]
```

any Ruby methods which support the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) into the resulting array and [`#fill`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-fill) the last element with the necessary number of `false` elements:

```rb
array = ["1", "b", "0", "7", "9", "2", "a", "a", "5", "7"]
array
  .each_slice(3)
  .to_a
  .tap { |a| a.last.fill(false, a.last.length, 3 - a.last.length) }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can count the number of needed padding elements with:

```
-array.size % chunk_size
```

By chaining enumerators, it's possible to perform the padding like in [iGian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56413803/681520) without creating an intermediate array or touching the original array:

```
> [1, 2, 3] + [4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
> [1,2,3].each + [4]
=> #<Enumerator::Chain: ...>
> ([1,2,3].each + [4]).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Make a method out of it:

```
def padded_each_slice(array, chunk_size = 3, pad = false)
  (array.each + Array.new(-array.size % chunk_size, pad)).each_slice(chunk_size)
end
```

And let's put it to the test:

```
> array = ["1", "b", "0", "7", "9", "2", "a", "a", "5", "7"]
> padded_each_slice(array).to_a
=> [["1", "b", "0"], ["7", "9", "2"], ["a", "a", "5"], ["7", false, false]]

> array << '1'
> padded_each_slice(array).to_a
=> [["1", "b", "0"], ["7", "9", "2"], ["a", "a", "5"], ["7", "1", false]]

> array << '2'
> padded_each_slice(array).to_a
=> [["1", "b", "0"], ["7", "9", "2"], ["a", "a", "5"], ["7", "1", "2"]]

> array << '3'
> padded_each_slice(array).to_a
=> [["1", "b", "0"], ["7", "9", "2"], ["a", "a", "5"], ["7", "1", "2"], ["3", false, false]]
```

Maybe not that beautiful, but wanted to add an answer with chained enumerators, which are a new feature introduced in Ruby 2.6.

Includes an improvement suggested by [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan) in the comments.

Comment: Using `-array.size % chunk_size` to calculate the number of padding elements allows you to get rid of the condition.

Comment: This answer, as well as @iGian's, has the weakness that it constructs an intermediate array that is at least as large as original one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland this answer doesn't create such array: `+` is called on the array's `each` enumerator, not `array` itself.

Comment: BTW, it might be cleaner to use `array.chain(other)` instead of `array.each + other`.

Comment: @Stefan, thanks. Kimmo, my comment was a result of a lazy reading of your answer, for which I apologize. I was not aware of [Enumerator#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-2B) and [Enumerable#chain](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chain), but as I found they were introduced in v2.6, that's perhaps not too surprising. (You might mention that they're new in your answer.)...

Comment: ...Suppose `e = [1,2].each + [3]; e.class #=> Enumerator::Chain; e.method(:next) #=>  #<Method: Enumerator::Chain(Enumerator)#next>`, showing `e` inherits `Enumerator#next`. I therefore would expect `e.next #=> 1`, yet `e.next #=> TypeError (wrong argument type chain (expected enumerator))`. Can you or @Stefan or anyone else explain?

Comment: @CarySwoveland looks like a bug to me. `e = ([1,2].each + [3]).each` or `e = [1,2].chain([3]).each` work as expected.

Comment: @Stefan, let me mull it. If I (or you or anyone else) cannot reason it's not a bug, I'll report it, in which case I'll leave a comment here containing a link to the report.

Comment: I originally had `(array.each + other.each).each_slice` but accidentally left the latter .each out, but it appeared to work.

Comment: @CarySwoveland report it, please. The docs for [`Enumerable::Chain`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator/Chain.html) claim that it is _"[…] a chain of enumerables that works as a single enumerator"_. But it raises exceptions for almost all `Enumerator` methods (`next`, `peek`, `each_with_index` etc). I'm quite used to bugs in casual software, even operating systems, but it always baffles me to see broken (or sloppy) implementations in programming languages.

Comment: @Stefan, okay, I'll do that tomorrow. btw, I think you mean `each_index`.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 3
arr = ["1", "b", "0", "7", "9", "2", "a", "a", "5", "7"]

arr.each_slice(n).map { |a| n.times.map { |i| a.fetch(i, false) } }
  #=> [["1", "b", "0"], ["7", "9", "2"], ["a", "a", "5"], ["7", false, false]]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
n = 3
arr = ["1", "b", "0", "7", "9", "2", "a", "a", "5", "7"]
enum0 = arr.each_slice(n)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["1", "b", "0", "7", "9", "2", "a", "a",
  #                  "5", "7"]:each_slice(3)> 
enum1 = enum0.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["1", "b", "0", "7", "9", "2", "a",
  #                                "a", "5", "7"]:each_slice(3)>
```

This uses the form of [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) that does not have a block. Look at the return value of `enum1`. It can be thought of as a *compound enumerator*, though Ruby has no such concept. Note:

```
enum1.each  { |a| n.times.map { |i| a.fetch(i, false) } }
  #=> [["1", "b", "0"], ["7", "9", "2"], ["a", "a", "5"], ["7", false, false]]
```

See [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-each).

The first element of `enum1` is generated and passed to the block, and the block variable `a` is assigned its value:

```
a = enum1.next
  #=> ["1", "b", "0"]
```

See [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-fetch). The block calculation is now performed:

```
enum2 = n.times.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: 3:times>:map>
i = enum2.next
  #=> 0
a.fetch(i, false)
  #=> ["1", "b", "0"].fetch(0, false)
  #=> "1"
i = enum2.next
  #=> 1
a.fetch(i, false)
  #=> ["1", "b", "0"].fetch(1, false)
  #=> "b"
i = enum2.next
  #=> 2
a.fetch(i, false)
  #=> ["1", "b", "0"].fetch(2, false)
  #=> "0"
i = enum2.next
  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

`map` therefore returns `["1", "b", "0"]`. The calculations are similar for:

```
enum1.next
  #=> ["7", "9", "2"]
```

and

```
enum1.next
  #=> ["a", "a", "5"]
```

In all those cases we could have used `a[i]` in place of `a.fetch(i, false)`.

Lastly,

```
a = enum1.next
  #=> ["7"] 
enum2 = n.times.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: 3:times>:map>
enum2.each { |i| a.fetch(i, false) }
  #=> ["7", false, false]
```

As before, `enum2` passes `0`, `1` and `2` to the block. In the latter two cases, [Array#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-fetch) returns its *default value*, `false`, because the index is out-of-bounds.

Comment: For readers who, like me, have never seen a vote to "delete" (as opposed to, say "close"), it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). I've gone through the criteria for deleting or voting to delete and find nothing that seems to apply, so I'm left perplexed.

Comment: By chance, I saw your comment, Cary. It isn't clear what has perplexed you (I can't see any pending close votes) but I wonder if it was the downvote. That was mine, and apologies - I though it was self-explanatory. Code-only answers are a risky bet on Stack Overflow - they are a subject of some contention [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-only-answers). My view is that the learning opportunity for future readers (not including the OP) would be much expanded if some initial explanatory text is provided.

Comment: I don't do Ruby, but I wonder if there is some additional material that you could add to preface this?

Comment: Thanks for owning-up, @halfer. I edited, but I think that in this case the need for an explanation is borderline. In for a penny, in for a pound, so I provided one of my "excruciating-detail" explanations. I wasn't perplexed by the downvote but by the "delete(1)" (maybe only I can see that). Perhaps a moderator did that for the same reason you downvoted. Incidentally, my practice is to always leave a comment if I downvote or vote to close. If I think an answer has merit but requires a fuller explanation, I leave a comment to that effect, but rarely downvote if the OP takes no action.

Comment: No worries. Yes, I cannot see a delete vote (either on the question or your answer) - it may be a 20k privilege. Thanks for the edits - that's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I _personally_ tend to comment on my downvotes, but I do not require others to - there is occasionally a tendency towards revenge downvoting on the platform, and I can certainly understand why new users are fearful of it. I haven't experienced it a great deal, but I do tend to get the most, erm, "robust feedback" from 20k+ users, which may be why I did not comment previously.

Comment: @halfer, I've experienced what I believe to have been revenge downvoting. Curiously, it brings a knowing smile to my face. When there's a pattern, I flag.

Comment: Oh yeah, it does not bother me, and I happily flag too `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Other option

```
ary = ["1", "b", "0", "7", "9", "2", "a", "a", "5", "7"]
n = 3
ary.then { |ary| ary + Array.new(- ary.size % n){false} }.each_slice(n)#.to_a
```

It fills the missing elements before to slice.

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

```
> array.each_slice(3).to_a.map{|e| Array.new(3){e.empty? ? false: e.shift }}
#=> [["1", "b", "0"], ["7", "9", "2"], ["a", "a", "5"], ["7", false, false]]
```

to fill missing element with `nil`

```
> array.each_slice(3).to_a.map{|e| Array.new(3){e.shift }}
#=> [["1", "b", "0"], ["7", "9", "2"], ["a", "a", "5"], ["7", nil, nil]]
```